# why does my code throw a "bean not managed exception"?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

My code has been working fine with just a single  repository package, until I began adding more repository & entity packages in my data source config class. The code failed with the exception :`... Error creating bean with name 'waecChemistryObjRepo' defined in com.example.resource.akademiks.waec.obj.dao.WaecChemistryObjRepo defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on AkademiksDbConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.resource.akademiks.waec.obj.entity.WaecChemistryObj`

Primary data source config class:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.resource.akademiks.waec.obj.dao",
        "com.example.resource.akademiks.waec.theory.dao", "com.example.resource.akademiks.waec.theory.answer.dao"},
 entityManagerFactoryRef = "akademiksEntityManagerFactory",
 transactionManagerRef = "akademiksTransactionManager")
public class AkademiksDbConfig {
    
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.waecakademiks")
    public DataSourceProperties akademiksDataSourceProperties() {
        
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }
    
    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.waecakademiks")
    public DataSource akademiksDataSource() {
        
        return akademiksDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
        
    }
    
    
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "akademiksEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
    akademiksEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        
        return builder
                .dataSource(akademiksDataSource())
                .packages("com.example.resource.akademiks.waec.obj.entity")
                .packages("com.example.resource.akademiks.waec.theory.questions.entity")
                .packages("com.example.resource.akademiks.waec.theory.answer.entity")
                .build();
                
    }
    
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager akademiksTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("akademiksEntityManagerFactory")
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean akademiksEntityManagerFactory
            ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(akademiksEntityManagerFactory.getObject());
    }
    
}
```

Repository:

```
package com.example.resource.akademiks.waec.obj.dao;

@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "chemistry", path = "chemistry")
public interface WaecChemistryObjRepo extends JpaRepository<WaecChemistryObj, Integer> {
```

service layers:

```
 package com.example.resource.akademiks.waec.theory.chemistry.service;

public interface WaecChemistryTheoryService {}
```

Service implementation:

```
 @Service
   public class WaecChemistryObjServiceImpl implements WaecChemistryObjService {
  @Autowired
 private WaecChemistryObjOptionRepo chemistryOptionRepo;
```

entity class:

```
package com.example.resource.akademiks.waec.obj.entity;

@Entity
@Table(name = "WaecChemistryObjAnswer")
public class WaecChemistryObjAnswer {
```

Other entities and repositories have been excluded.

Comment: You are using Spring Boot. Why do you configure everything yourself?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, I have multiple data source configuration. There's no other simpler way I could do it than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`packages`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.Builder.html#packages-java.lang.String...-) method takes a varargs parameter:

```
EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.Builder packages(String... packagesToScan)
```

You call it 3 times instead of passing 3 packages in a single call.

More generally: take advantage of auto-configuration and follow convention over configuration approach, as suggested in comments.